# Java Jar -java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport from

Tags: java, google-api-client, google-api-java-client, google-search-console, google-oauth-java-client

i am using webmaster tool Java api V3 to query data , my code work fine in eclipse  but when i export it to a Jar i get the error below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:430)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1061)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:506)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:498)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:665)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:942)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:851)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:82
```

my dependecies are as follow

[image]

[image]

i am compiling and exporting the jar in Java6 and executing it using Java7.

i assume it's a dependency issue but i don't know how to resolve it ?? espically it's working in eclipse but when i export the jar from eclipse keeping the default config and selecting the main class i get `NoClassDefFoundError` ,  any ideas thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get this error when class com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport *IS* available during compilation but is *NOT* available at runtime.

Eclipse automatically adds the jar files on the *build* classpath to your *runtime* configuration's classpath. Therefore you won't get the Exception when you're running from Eclipse.

I'm assuming you are running form the command line like this:
`java -cp myjarfile.jar com.my.Main`

If this is the case, the classpath is missing the dependencies as configured in Eclipse. To solve this, append each of them as follows:
`java -cp myjarfile.jar;commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;etc... com.my.Main`

Note that the semi-colon `;` in the classpath  is for Windows. Use a colon `:` on Linux.

**Update**
When using a runnable jar file, make sure your class path is correctly set in the manifest file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: but i added all the jars to the class path

Comment: Please show how. Copy/paste the command line you are using to start the application e.g. java -cp ... so we can give better feedback

Comment: it's resolved i just exported a runnable jar from eclipse then executed it using java -jar majar.jar

Comment: Great! Glad you solved it. I've updated my answer with the -jar strategy.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the problem by exporting runnable Jar from eclipse instead of Jar.